# Socket connection ActiveMQ with .Net

Tags: activemq-classic, amqp, amq

I have a task where I need to establish a connection between an ActiveMQ queue and a .Net application. I am using the AMQP.Net Lite plugin for this. But I have a need for the receiver of the .Net application to be called the moment the message goes into the queue.
Is there any solution where there is no need for the .Net application to stay from time to time by checking the MQ queue to see if there is any new message?
Any direct connection using socket? how should I proceed in this case?

Comment: Looks more suitable, when you show us what have you tried, and what the exact issue is, so that the same can be given a possible solution .. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Adan-

Sounds like you want to setup a standard consumer (or it may be called a receiver). Your use case is exactly the purpose of the consumer-side of the AMQP API.. see below

Note: Messaging systems often deploy a 'callback' or 'listener' model for asynchronous processing when receiving messages. That will still feel "instantaneous" from a data processing perspective. It is a different programming paradigm that is simpler to code as it does not require logic to break out of an infinite loop in the receiver/consumer pattern.

[AMQP.NET lite receiver sample](https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite/blob/master/Examples/PeerToPeer/PeerToPeer.Receiver/Program.cs#L159)